# Is there a way to stop web methods from working when the project stops running in .NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I'm working on an application which has to use VB.NET on server side.
Basically, I'm calling WebMethods from JavaScript using AJAX. (More precisely, JQuery's AJAX function)

While it's all good and I have no problem receiving and uploading data, there's something that is still bothering me.

Even after I stop the project from running, I still retain all the functionality from the WebMethods on client side. In fact, I can stop the project from running, then press 'Add to Cart' client side which calls a WebMethod that adds some records into a database. If I then check my database, the new records are there, even though the project was not running.

I figured I could at least check to see if the session was alive in order to prevent this from happening but to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Here's how I'm checking to see if the session is still alive:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Shared Function AddToCart(ByVal itemCode As String, ByVal company As String) As String
    If (HttpContext.Current.Session("spusrid") IsNot Nothing) Then
        '//Its all good keep going!
    Else
        Return "ERROR-20"

    End If

    '//Remainder of code which adds Item to cart.

End If
```

If it helps at all, I'm running the project locally.
I'm just worried the behavior will carry on to the live site.

Comment: You mean when the project stops running in Visual Studio? Are you running it on local computer or in a remote context?

Comment: I edited my post, Yes I'm running it locally.
I'm just worried the behavior will carry on to the live site.

Comment: "Even after I stop the project from running"... sounds like you stopped Visual Studio debugger and not your real app server most likely IIS

Comment: This doesn't happen when you deploy to IIS on a non-VS environment, because it'll be running in a different manner. It's just a debugging thing, as Jason's answer describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Visual Studio has fired up the project in IIS Express. If that's the case, it should show up in your system tray and you can kill that specific site. An alternative is to close the project in Visual Studio, and that will stop the site from running as well.

Comment: Okay, apparently Visual studio keeps the project running in IIS even if you stop the project from running. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely! For future reference, VS 2013 has an "Edit and Continue" feature that will stop it from running when you kill the project, but also allows you edit code while running.